# Bit.ly link without http://

Tags: microsoft-excel, links

I am creating bitly links and want to save them in an Excel spreadsheet.

When I copy and paste them I get the http:// component of the address in front of the bit.ly

How can I not get this as it takes up space in the cell?

Comment: Delete the characters?

Comment: How do you create these links? Is there some automatism that you are using?

Comment: Where are you copying them from? If you are copying the link from the browsers address bar then most browsers will fully qualify the URL as it is copied (although this might not be shown in the address bar itself). However, Opera allows you to show the entire URL, so you can copy just the part of the URL that you require.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the string after the fact.

1. Click the column header to select the column
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the "Find + Replace" dialog
3. Put "http://" in the text to find; leave the text to replace blank
4. Click `OK`